# VBA - Adding frames to UserForm programmatically, at design mode not at run time

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I need to edit my existing form (testFORM)...add 80 pictures.

I don't want to make it at run time but permanently change my form.

Here is code in Module1:

```
Sub addImage()
Dim imgNew As Object
Dim imgNewCounter As Integer
For imgNewCounter = 1 To 80
    Set imgNew = testFORM.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1")
    With imgNew
        .Name = "Image" & imgNewCounter
        .Left = 24
        .Width = 20
        .Height = 10
        .BackColor = RGB(26, 25, 50)
        .Top = 5
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: what is TESTFORM?  should your title read Programmatically?

Comment: testFORM is name of my userform in VBA, yes programmatically...

Answer (score 1):

Using VBA extensibility, you can do the following....

```
Sub CreateTextBox()


Dim vbp As VBProject
Dim vbc As VBComponent

Set vbp = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject
Set vbc = vbp.VBComponents("Userform1")

vbc.Designer.Controls.Add "forms.textbox.1", "newcontrol"


End Sub
```