# VBA Controls disappear after finishing the macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that generates a Label, TextBox and SpinButton in a Userform. When I run the code the Controls are being added into the form and after running it they will stay there until I close the form. How can I make them permanent in the form?
I need this code because I have to create hundreds of them and give them a code. I do not want to do it manually.

```
Sub Temp()

    TempLeft = 10
    TempTop = 10
    TempTop2 = 40
    b = 0

    Dim lbl As MSForms.Label
    Dim edtBox_n As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim SpinButton As MSForms.SpinButton

    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim LineNum As Long

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Set VBProj = wb.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("LoR_UserForm")
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    Dim Textname As String
    Dim Spinname As String
    Textname = "Textbox" & b
    Spinname = "Spinbutton" & b

    LoR_UserForm.Show Modeless

    Do Until i > 3000
        If ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Interior.Color = 16716287 Then
            
            Set lbl = LoR_UserForm.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Label" & b, True)
            lbl.Caption = ActiveCell.Offset(i - 1, 1) & "_" & ActiveCell.Offset(i, 1) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(i + 1, 1) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(i + 2, 1)
            lbl.BackColor = RGB(128, 128, 128)
            lbl.Left = TempLeft
            lbl.Top = TempTop + 60
            lbl.Height = 50
            lbl.Width = 100

            Set edtBox_n = LoR_UserForm.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "Textbox" & b, True)
            edtBox_n.Left = TempLeft + 100
            edtBox_n.Top = TempTop + 60
            edtBox_n.Height = 20
            edtBox_n.Width = 20

            Set SpinButton = LoR_UserForm.Controls.Add("Forms.Spinbutton.1", "Spinbutton" & b, True)
            SpinButton.Left = TempLeft + 100
            SpinButton.Top = TempTop2 + 60
            SpinButton.Height = 20
            SpinButton.Width = 20

            Textname = "Textbox" & b
            Spinname = "Spinbutton" & b
            LineNum = 1
            CodeMod.InsertLines LineNum, "Private Sub " & Spinname & "_Change()"
            LineNum = LineNum + 1
            CodeMod.InsertLines LineNum, Textname & ".Value = " & Spinname & ".Value"
            LineNum = LineNum + 1
            CodeMod.InsertLines LineNum, "End Sub"
            TempTop = TempTop + 60
            TempTop2 = TempTop2 + 60
            b = b + 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

after closing form:
[image]

while running:
[image]

I tried playing with the visibility of the controls. I also looked into the userform-menu where all the objects in said userform are listed and they were not. Only those that are in both photos visible.

Comment: just a guess: what's the behaviour if you add the controls first, before showing the form?

Comment: Controls added via code will only show during runtime, this is expected behavior.

Comment: You can add/edit controls in design mode using VBA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825993/vba-adding-frames-to-userform-programmatically-at-design-mode-not-at-run-time

Comment: Thank you guys, putting .Designer. into the Code solved my Problem